# Bootstrap switch looks all wrong

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-switch

We are developing a web based tool and we are using bootstrap switches.

Our switch looks like this:

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" id="planned" name="planned" class="switch">
</td>
```

The width of the `<td>` is set with the `<th>` and is 130px.

This is the JS:

```
$(".switch").bootstrapSwitch({
    onText: "Yes",
    offText: "No"
});
```

It looks like this in IE11 (all we have access to at work) but looks fine in firefox and chrome. Any ieas?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgcfhgqt/4/)

Comment: Looks like something's causing it to overflow onto the next line, we'll probably need to see either a working example or more of the CSS to be able to help much.

Comment: See this [Issue](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch/issues/591) on GitHub.